# Loop through array of objects to find if one value differs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops, object

I have an array of objects and want to tell if one of the objects' value differs from the rest.

```
$scope.myArray = [{name:'ted', age:'18', gender: 'm'},
                  {name:'bob', age:'18', gender: 'm'},
                  {name:'ben', age:'19', gender: 'm'}
];
```

Now I loop over them...

```
angular.forEach($scope.myArray, function(value, key) {
  console.log(value.age);
  //logs 18, 18, 19
  //how to I evaluate if one of the ages is different?
});
```

Comment: You can compare each age with `$scope.myArray[0].age`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do somethng like this

```
angular.forEach($scope.myArray, function(value, key) {
    if ($scope.myArray[0].age != value.age){
        $scope.isDifferent = true;
        return false;           
    }           
 });
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2hkf87x/)